# How to modify the head of a LinkedList without a wrapper class?

Tags: java, linked-list, singly-linked-list

When I create a Node object and call "appendToTail" the Node object has a sequence of nodes via the next attribute (as expected). I tried creating a pop, where it takes the head (aka 'this') and reference it with a variable and overwrite it with its next. However, 'this' remains the same as the original head. What am I doing wrong, or is there no way to modify 'this'?

```
public class Node {
    Node next = null;
    int data;

    public Node(int d) {
        data = d;
    }

    public void appendToTail(int d) {
        Node end = new Node(d);
        Node n = this;
        while (n.next != null) {
            n = n.next;
        }
        n.next = end;
    }

    public void popHead() {
        Node n = this;
        n = n.next;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't modify `this`. It always refers to a given object. A Node itself shouldn't know what the Head is. There should a List class that hold information about what the head is and you should modify that.

Comment: You want to achieve something like FIFO queue?

Comment: `this` is a *keyword*, not a *variable*. It lets us get reference to *current* object but it doesn't let us *modify* that reference. Anyway why would you want to do it in the first place? This feels like [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Comment: i suppose you could replace the data in head with node 2's data, set head's reference to node 2's reference, then delete node 2. this would be convoluted and not ideal though and i would just use a wrapper

Comment: Thanks everyone! I was reading Cracking the Coding Interview and they had this as an example and mentioned that if other objects referenced this node, they would still reference the old head if it was replaced...what I was confused about is, with this example, how can you even change the head? The only way I could think of doing so is with a wrapper list class.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to construct a custom List and add each node at End. Also you need to store first node in order to have the starting point for looping.

```
public class NodeList
{
    Node head=null;
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        NodeList nl = new NodeList();
        nl.addNode(1);
        nl.addNode(2);
        nl.addNode(3);
        nl.listNodes();
    }
    
    public void addNode(int data)
    {
        if(head==null)
        {
            head = new Node(data);
        }
        else
        {
            Node curent = head;
            while(curent.next != null)
            {
                curent = curent.next;       
            }
            curent.next = new Node(data);
        }
    }
    
    public void listNodes()
    {
        if(head !=null)
        {
            Node curent = head;
            System.out.println(curent.data);
            while(curent.next !=null)
            {
                curent = curent.next;
                System.out.println(curent.data);
            }
        }
    }
    
    class Node 
    {
        Node next = null;
        int data;

        public Node(int d) {
            data = d;
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
1
2
3
```